# Statsmodels: Removes invalid rows from data, but not from weights

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a `pandas` dataframe with the columns `x`, `y`, `w` where `w` is the weights. There is many missing values on `x` and `y`. Without weights, the following works

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
smf.ols('y ~ x', data=df')
```

Then I want to use the weights, and I do:

```
smf.wls('y ~ x', data=df', weights=df['w'])
```

and get

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (153704,1) (81522,6)
```

*where my regression contains 4 dependent variables, which explains the `6` in the error (4 + dependent + intercept)*.

I guess that the issue is that there is missing values, which `statsmodels` is cleaning for me. Then, that reduces the number of rows from `153704` to `81522`, while it doesn't apparently do that adjustment on the weights - which leads to the missmatch. Is there any quick workaround here? Am I using the `weights` argument properly? This - in my mind - is a standard problem and shouldn't really be surprising...

Comment: Hey FooBar, I'm having the exact same problem. Let me know if you've found a cure for this. Thanks.

Comment: @RachelShuyanWang As far as I remember, I didn't find any out-of-the-box solution, so I ended up cleaning the data (removing missing in all columns, hence aligning the data) in `pandas` first.

Comment: ok yeah that's what i did too.